# Erro ao incluir session ou foreach no código PHP

Tags: php, session, foreach

Estou estudando PHP com um livro que comprei e o exercício é criar uma lista de tarefas. O navegador está me retornando o seguinte erro:

> Notice: Undefined variable: lista_tarefas in C:\Users\elton\Desktop\Cadastro\root\ListaDeTarefas\template.php on line 26
>
> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\Users\elton\Desktop\Cadastro\root\ListaDeTarefas\template.php on line 26
> Tarefas

O trecho com erro em template.php é esse código:

```
<table>
    <tr>
       <th>Tarefas</th>
    </tr>
    <?php foreach($lista_tarefas as $tarefa) : ?>
    <tr>
       <td><?php echo $tarefa; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</table>
```

E o código PHP que estou usando é este:

```
<?php 

session_start();

    if (array_key_exists('nome', $_GET)){ 
        $_SESSION['lista_tarefas'][] = $_GET['nome'];
    }
    $lista_tarefas = [];
            
    if (array_key_exists('lista_tarefas', $_SESSION)){
        $lista_tarefas  = $_SESSION['lista_tarefas'];
    }

?>
```

Por favor, me ajudem a entender onde estou errando. Não consegui chegar até o erro.

Comment: Adiciona a _URL_ que você está usando para acessar o arquivo pra gente poder analisar melhor, pois seu arquivo está recebendo parâmetros via _GET_.

Comment: Esses dois trechos de código estão no mesmo arquivo ou são arquivos distintos?

Comment: http://localhost:8079/ListaDeTarefas/template.php?nome=d

Comment: Estão em arquivos distintos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como você está utilizando arquivos distintos, nesse `foreach` não vai existir a variável `$lista_tarefas`, pois ela não foi criada:

```
<?php
    foreach ($lista_tarefas as $tarefa):
        ...
    endforeach;
```

Esse é o motivo do erro:

> Notice: Undefined variable: lista_tarefas in C:\Users\elton\Desktop\Cadastro\root\ListaDeTarefas\template.php on line 26

Acredito que você teria que adicionar esse trecho de código antes do `foreach` no mesmo arquivo (no topo da página, antes do código *HTML* é o local mais indicado):

```
<?php
    session_start();

    if (array_key_exists('nome', $_GET)){ 
        $_SESSION['lista_tarefas'][] = $_GET['nome'];
    }
    $lista_tarefas = [];

    if (array_key_exists('lista_tarefas', $_SESSION)){
        $lista_tarefas  = $_SESSION['lista_tarefas'];
    }
```

Comment: Funcionou direitinho. Eu consegui chegar no ponto que queria com este apoio, obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
session_start();


if (array_key_exists('nome', $_GET)){ 
    $_SESSION['lista_tarefas'][] = $_GET['nome'];
}
$lista_tarefas = [];

if (array_key_exists('lista_tarefas', $_SESSION)){
    $lista_tarefas  = $_SESSION['lista_tarefas'];
}


include './template.php';
```

Seu codigo precisa ficar assim, como o amigo de cima disse, você precisa incluir o html dentro do php, ou o php dentro do html, o melhor a se fazer é incluir o arquivo que tem o php dentro do arquivo do template, mas como eu n sei qual arquivo é eu fiz ao contrario, vai  funcionar do mesmo jeito, só q vc vai precisar o executar o arquivo php e nao o template.php

Comment: Valeu man. Sua ajuda foi grande valor!